# Generate custom order no based on date, 3 alphabet code and auto incremented serial no

Tags: mysql

I have the below table:

```
create table test
(
ID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
CreatedOn datetime not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
OrderNo varchar(100) not null,
Primary Key (ID)
);
```

I wondering if I can have the order no something like this: DNB1605141

- DNB - is the 3 letter code
- 16 - is the current year - need to be    picked up from createdon column or current timestamp
- 05 - is the current month for that year - need to be    picked up from createdon column or current timestamp
- 14 - is the    current date - need to be picked up from createdon column or current    timestamp
- 1 - is the first order

But with one condition, at the start of every month the serial no should reseed to 1.

For example: DNB1605011 (1st order for 1st May 2016), DNB1606011 (1st order for 1st June 2016)

I am writing a stored procedure to insert the values into the table. But I am not sure how to generate the Order No.

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Why is this question tagged both `mysql` and `tsql`. T-SQL is the dialect used with SQL-Server, not MySQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: MySQL. I have now un-tagged t-sql

Comment: With the reset requirement, this might be easiest to do in the application logic rather than mySQL itself...

Comment: I think you would need another table that holds the sequence number, which you increment and concatenate onto the order number here. Then you could use the Event Scheduler to reset that table back to 1 at the beginning of each month.

Comment: This seems like a strange requirement. The date information is in the `CreatedOn` column, why do you need to encode into the `OrderNo`? Why not just use `ID` as the order number?

Comment: I gave a thought on using the ID column initially, but if the ID is like 10000+ the order no will have that much values. The main aim is to provide better room for orders to be generated in a given month. I can probably have 1000 orders in a given month or 10K in another month. I will be easily able to differentiate. Thanks. Please let me know your thoughts on this idea. This logic was inbuilt into old app that was developed in windows. I am building a new app in php mysql and the customer wants to retain the same logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating and monitoring via Scheduler event, I figured out to check this via date functions. Before the insert while creating the order no it will check if the DAYOFMONTH is 1, If Yes then it will reseed the Order No to 1 else it will pick up the max order no. I am storing the order no in a separate column and the prefix in a separate column.

For DNB1605141: DNB1605 in column A and 141 in column B

Here is the code for the order no generation:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spCashDonation$$
CREATE PROCEDURE spCashDonation(IN fname varchar(50),IN lname varchar(50),IN telNo bigint, IN pmode tinyint,IN amt decimal(13,2), OUT rno varchar(20))
BEGIN
    Set @rmain := (select trim(concat('DNB', DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%y'), DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%m'))));

    IF ((trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) = 01) OR (trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) = 1)) THEN
        Set @rpart = 1;
    END IF;

    IF ((trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) != 01) OR (trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) != 1)) THEN
        Set @rpart := (select coalesce(max(ReceiptPart),0) from Donation) + 1;
    END IF;

 INSERT INTO Donation (ReceiptMain, ReceiptPart, firstName, lastName, telNo, payMode, Amount) VALUES (@rmain, @rpart, fname, lname, telNo, pmode, amt);

 Set @lid := (select max(LAST_INSERT_ID()));
        select concat(ReceiptMain,ReceiptPart) into rno from donation where id = @lid;

 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the next OrderNo by doing a count as follows:

```
select count(1) + 1 as NextOrderNo
 FROM test
 where date_format(CreatedOn, '%Y') = date_format(current_date(), '%Y')
   and date_format(CreatedOn, '%m') = date_format(current_date(), '%m');
```

Possibly work this into a sub-select of your insert statement.

You should consider the effects of a multi-threaded environment,
there is a possibility of duplicate OrderNo values within the same month-year
if multiple threads insert concurrently.

Comment: To avoid duplicate inserts may be I can use a lock?

Comment: Yes, table locks can help avoid the duplicates.